# Failed to download dompdf/dompdf Laravel Composer

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, composer-php

I am running this from my local machine by XAMPP. I tried to install several times and it is still giving me the same error. Tried to ping google.com, and shows no error (To clear my self that this is not DNS issue). Nothing specific was found related to this on GitHub issues.

When I try to require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf by Composer I get this error.

```
Failed to download dompdf/dompdf from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/dompdf/dompdf/zipball/5113accd9ae5d466077cce5208dcf3fb871bf8f6" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
```

Below is copied details from bash.

```
$ composer require barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
Using version ^0.8.2 for barryvdh/laravel-dompdf
./composer.json has been updated
Loading composer repositories with package information
Updating dependencies (including require-dev)
Package operations: 5 installs, 0 updates, 0 removals
  - Installing sabberworm/php-css-parser (8.1.0): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phenx/php-svg-lib (v0.3.2): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing phenx/php-font-lib (0.5.1): Downloading (100%)
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.2): Downloading (90%)
Downloading (failed)
Downloading (failed)    Failed to download dompdf/dompdf from dist: The "https://api.github.com/repos/dompdf/dompdf/zipball/5113accd9ae5d466077cce5208dcf3fb871bf8f6" file could not be downloaded: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
failed to open stream: php_network_getaddresses: getaddrinfo failed: No such host is known.
    Now trying to download from source
  - Installing dompdf/dompdf (v0.8.2): Cloning 5113accd9a


  [RuntimeException]
  Failed to clone https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf.git via https, ssh protocols, aborting.
  - https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf.git
    Cloning into 'D:\xampp\htdocs\rtdo\vendor\dompdf\dompdf'...
    fatal: unable to access 'https://github.com/dompdf/dompdf.git/': Could not resolve host: github.com
  - git@github.com:dompdf/dompdf.git
    Cloning into 'D:\xampp\htdocs\rtdo\vendor\dompdf\dompdf'...
    ssh: Could not resolve hostname github.com: Name or service not known
    fatal: Could not read from remote repository.

    Please make sure you have the correct access rights
    and the repository exists.
```

If you need further details let me know. Thank You!

Comment: _"Could not resolve host: github.com"_ <- it's a DNS issue

Comment: @phil So how could I solve it?

Comment: @Hodor you just can't. Github is sometimes unreachable. Maybe it is related to the fact that MS bought Github :-D

Comment: @czende there should be a solution.